# Hide/Unhide Rows depending on Formula-based result showing on a cell in that row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am struggling with finding a VBA code to deal with this situation :
Q23 to Q73 are cells with formulas on them so i don't make any entries on them manually.

Rows 24 to 73 are usually hidden but i need them to unhide automatically if Q24 to Q73 displays any result and return to being hidden if they are empty (Formula result displayed is "").

Comment: Did U mean to say if Q24 to Q73 does have either data/Number/Text or even Formula should be un-hidden otherwise hidden!! This you want to work with any of the cells or entire range Q24:Q73 ?

Comment: @RajeshS , Q23~Q73 contain formulas of this sort =IF(B250="Yes";C250;"") - all the data entering happens on rows below row 105 so my Q cells can only show a number (since C250 contains a number) or show nothing but the formulas are already there and working.fine - i need the VBA code to be able to only unhide only the rows that are displaying something and keep the empty one hidden. and ofc hide them back once i reset all the data entries.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for in the sheet code (change sheet1 to the correct sheet), not in a module.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim MyRnge As Range, c As Range
Set MyRnge = Sheet1.Range("A2:A50")
For Each c In MyRnge
    If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

OR

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim MyRnge As Range, c As Range
Set MyRnge = Sheet1.Range("A2:A50")

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$B$1")) Is Nothing Then

For Each c In MyRnge
    If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

OR Hides even numbered rows when odd changed between range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$N$21:$N$73")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Row Mod 2 <> 0 Then
If Target <> vbNullString Then
Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = False
Else
Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = True
End If
End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

OR hides next row between range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$N$21:$N$73")) Is Nothing Then

If Target <> vbNullString Then
Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = False
Else
Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = True
End If
End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Clear cells/ranges syntax:

```
Sub ClearApp()
'ClearApp Macro
Cells(14, 6).MergeArea.ClearContents 'clear merged area - you can refer to any of the cells within the merged range. This clears the A14 merged area in your example by referring to F16 within the merged area.
Range("J1:J9,K1:K9").ClearContents 'clear any other area
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for your help! I used the code and it managed to unhide the rows as i wanted but 2 problems arised with it : 1) The run time is very long and freezes the spreadsheet preventing any kind of data entering as if all the cells got locked 2) As i tried to run the Clear Macro to check if hiding back works it bugged and showed 2 kinds:"Methode Hidden of object range failed" or  "run time error 1004 - Unable to set  the hidden property of the Range Class - As i pressed debug it selected "c.EntireRow.Hidden = False" gets filled Yellow. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Hi Kronos, sorry I should have had the calculate and screenupdating options in the code. Let me know if this does not fix the issues, just note that if the code fails it will leave calculation switched to manual and you will have to switch it back to automatic.NB - I have edited the code above

Comment: Thank you Justin! i tried it, the calculation sped up as i could see the rows unhide right away after i saved the code but it is still bugging and freezing the spreadsheet : "Methode Hidden of object range failed" or "run time error 1004 - As i pressed debug it selected "c.EntireRow.Hidden = False" gets filled Yellow. I also noticed that it seems to have some dominance conflict with Reset Data macro i use. the Reset macro got back to work only after i removed the Hinding/Unhiding Code completely. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: You could try linking it to a change event for the cells that result in the calculation of the formula, rather than the calculate event? Let me know if you want me to recode it that way.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand what you meant by that so yes if you could recode it i'd be able to try it.

Comment: Try replacing the calculate event code with the change event code above, change B1 to the cell that the formulas are linked to and the A2 to A50 to your range. If that does not fix it I will have to pass on to someone more knowledgable. If the formulae are linked to more than one cell we should be able to work out code if you give me the relevant ranges. NB - I just added the "IS NOTHING" to the if statement, make sure it is in your code.

Comment: Hi Justin, i couldn't figure out how to replace B1...to explain it in a better way, data entering is done by copy-pasting from an application to excel, the range used for the pasting in excel (original data) goes from A105:N750 and the results showing in the  Q12:Q73 are drawn using a crazy chain of data treatment formulas of IF, TRIM, INDEX and others to get only the hardly squeezed results showing in the Q12:Q73. That being said i think i figured out an easier way to go about it even though it is not as amazing as what it'd have been if we managed to fine tune the VBA code you made. Thanks!

Comment: Even with the alternative way i'm still unable to get it to work TT...TT. on cell N23 i have a drop down list that gives 3 random options out of the following codes (LE,MF,MG,OT,BK or empty "")..i wanted to make a code that would unhide row 24 if the selected code is anything other empty "" and was planing to repeat the condition for all following rows : N24 triggering row 25 and N25 triggering row 26 until i reach row 73 but nothing works >....<**** Please help, this is driving me nuts!!!

Comment: Can you link to an example version of what you are working with or have you posted elsewhere? I have an account with Ozgrid, if you could cross post your sheet there I can have a look, I am struggling to work out what you are after and seeing what you are working with would help a great deal. It does not sound like what you want should be difficult to achieve.

Comment: Hi Justin you can download the excel sheet via this link and thanks again:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fmKuynu4CMrUSzhphwJtDL-hsfhhV1n9    the range on this one is only Q23:Q41 but if it works it'd be easy to change it to Q73 and thanks again for your help!

Comment: HI Kronos, I have added code that hides the even numbered row immediately below any odd numbered row that is changed between the range N21 and N73. Let me know how it goes. I just reread the requirement, I will remove the odd even bit and just hide the row below based on the one above.

Comment: Hi Justin, it is working exactly as i wanted for the unhiding part but it is still bugging once i run the clear app macro. Btw the clear app macro on the exemple you have is not selecting all the data entry space so please change it as you need to check this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The version you uploaded has no macros attached, I am not sure if it is stripped from the sheets when you upload them or what the issue is. All I could get from the upload was a rough format and if I downloaded it there was no macro component. If you can share the sheet proper I can have a look at what is conflicting with the clear sheet macro.

Comment: Hi Justin, Please find the code of the macro i am using up in this conversation showing as an answer. kind regards,

Comment: I have added recommended syntax for the ClearApp macro, there may be a more efficient way to work with the merged ranges but I am not aware of it. Anywhere you have a merged range you will need to refer to one of the merged cells in the merged range using the syntax shown.

Comment: Actually what was bugging creating the bug is the order of execution of both macros: Setting that (n) is the row number, The unhiding macro is relying on the  N(n) to decide on whether to hide or unhide Row(n+1) starting with N23/Row24 ~ N71/Row72 - as for the Clearing Macro it has a random selection of selected cells that get selected and cleared in alphanumeric order from A to Z and from 1 to 10000 thus was starting the data deleting staring from N23 then N24, N25...which caused the bug coz N23 should be the last cell deleted as Row(24) is the last one to be hidden.

Comment: So i recorded macro of me deleting N71 followed by N70 followed by N69..till N23 and used the generated VBA code to replace the N23:N72 range and it worked =D a GREAT GREAT THANKS TO YOU JUSTIN!! i owe you big time!

Comment: You do not need to select or activate any of the cells in order to clear them, you do not need to scroll through the page. It will be horribly slow (particularly since you do not switch of screenupdating). Also if you are not selecting or activating whether the cells are visible is irrelevant to them being cleared.

Comment: I see...yeah true it's faster without the additional selection and scroll events =)

Comment: Cheers Kronos, can you tick this one off as solved if the code is working now.

Comment: Hi Justin, how to do that? Sorry i'm new to the forum...

Answer (score 0):

This is ClearApp macro i am using that i have made using the recording macro:

```
Sub ClearApp()
ClearApp Macro
Range( _
"B5:B7,E4:E7,C1,C2,F5,F7,A13:G13,A14:G21,A23:G82,H24:I82,J12:M82,N12:O82,N10:O10,J10:M10,V    7,V9,P73:AB82,W12:W82,A104:N779,C88:G88" _
    ).Select
Range("W12").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range( _
"B5:B7,E4:E7,C1,C2,F5,F7,A13:G13,A14:G21,A23:G82,H24:I82,J12:M82,N12:O82,N10:O10,J10:M10,V7,V9,P73:AB82,W12:W82,A104:N779,C88:G88" _
    ).Select
Range("A49").Activate
Sheets("test").Select
 Selection.ClearContents
End sub
```